# Is there a workaround to make opencensus work with MLFlow?

Tags: azure, mlflow, opencensus

I'm not able to import mlflow after having launched a log with opencensus Azure.
The MLFlow import runs forever.

My environment is the following:

- Python 3.7
- opencensus-ext-azure 1.0.7
- opencensus-ext-logging 0.1.0
- mlflow 1.15.0

Here is the code to repoduce the bug:

```py
import logging

from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=<your-key>'))
logger.warning('Hello, World!')

import mlflow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, not the cleanest one though.

I import mlflow at the beginning even if it's not useful this way:

```py
import mlflow
import logging

from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=<your-key>'))
logger.warning('Hello, World!')

import mlflow
```